# React charts breaking the lines issue

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-charts

I am using [React-Charts](https://react-charts.tanstack.com/) `3.0.0-beta.38`.

I am getting these charts (image below) when having a value equals `null`, I want something similar to `spanGaps` that exists on `chartjs`
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling.

So instead of breaking the lines, I want lines to be drawn between points with no or null data

[image]